# How to display the hover information based on a given x-value?

Tags: bokeh

I would like to display the hover information on a stocks plot based on a given x-value instead of the current mouse position.

EDIT: the x-value is set with a slider.

EDIT2:
I am running a folder app and use slider "on change" events. I want to pass the slider value to the plot. There are several plots and the slider just serves the function of highlighting a position simultaneously in all plots. Here is the relevant code:

```
slider.on_change('value', update_plots)

def update_plots(attr, old, new):
    # some code involving 'slider.value'
    # e.g. plot.set_hover_by_x_value(slider.value)
```

EDIT3:
A minimal example would be a single line plot and a slider that is used to highlight a point on the line:

```
p = figure(plot_width=400, plot_height=400)
p.line([1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [6, 7, 2, 4, 5], line_width=2)

slider = Slider(start=0, end=5, value=0, step=1, title='x-value')
slider.on_change('value', update_plots)

def update_plots(attr, old, new):
    # magic code to highlight the point "slider.value" in "p"
```

Answer (score 1):

As of Bokeh 1.1 there is no programmatic means to create hover tooltips. They are currently tied to explicit, actual UI interactions (e.g. a mouse moving and hitting a scatter point).

As an alternative, you could use a `Label` annotation to display information at a given location instead.

Comment: Any other alternatives? If I drop the requirement to display text information I might also use a simple visual highlight. Turn the line plot into a circle plot and change the size or color of the circle I want to highlight. I would like to avoid passing the whole `data.source` though.

Comment: I don't quite understand the question, but it seems to be looking for a general recommendation, so that discussion would be more appropriate for the the mailing list, not SO: https://groups.google.com/a/continuum.io/forum/#!forum/bokeh

Answer (score 0):

There are two kinds of tooltips in Bokeh:

- @: Associated with columns in a ColumnDataSource object
- $: Special fields such as coordinates of the mouse

In this case you should use @column_with_x_values in your tooltip list for your hovertool to show the given x-values.

More information on the hovertool and examples can be found on [this page](https://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/tools.html#basic-tooltips).

Comment: I am not sure what you mean. See edit 2 for my goals.

Comment: Is it possible to add some exampledata and all your code to your question? Then we can actually try to help instead of speculating what would be a possible solution.

Comment: is this enough? its just a basic line plot and a slider. the slider is used to highlight a point in the plot.